# How does --------------------------- work?

Tags: symbols, latex-misc, tex-general

When I type in

```
---------------------------
```

into LaTeX, it sometimes generates a continuous line like this:

[image]

However, if I don't have "sufficient" number of `-`, then sometimes the last `-` will not form a continuous line, like this:

[image]

What is the magic number of `-` you have to have in order to have a continuous line?

Comment: I'd say the 'magical' invocation you should use is: `\rule[<raise>]{<width>}{<thickness>}`. So `\rule[0.5ex]{4cm}{0.4pt}` prints a line that is 3cm 'long', 0.4pt 'thick', and 'raised' above the baseline by 0.5ex.  (The 'raise' argument is optional, of course.) Note how much more control this command has over writing an arbitrary number (but in multiples of 3) of hyphens.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The usual TeX convention is that two hyphens in a row generate an en-dash, while three generate an em-dash.

Consecutive em or en-dashes appear to form a solid line, although it is formed by distinct characters. However the hyphen does not combine, so if the number of hyphens is a multiple of three or one less than a multiple of three, you get a solid line. If the remainder of the division by three is one, you get a hyphen at the end.

However, solidity of the line depends on the font.

Plain TeX example

```
--------- % nine hyphens

-------- % eight hyphens

------- % seven hyphens

\bye
```

[image]

You *could* exploit this in order to make a long line (at least 0.5em), by superimposing en-dashes:

```
\def\solidline#1{%
  \leavevmode
  \hbox to #1{--\leaders\hbox{\kern-.125em--\kern-.125em}\hss--}%
}

\solidline{1cm}

\solidline{2em}

\solidline{1em}

\solidline{0.5em}

\bye
```

However, `\vrule` (or LaTeX's) rule is much more efficient. The same effect is obtained by

```
\def\solidline#1{%
  \vrule width #1 height 0.64ex depth\dimexpr0.2pt-0.64ex\relax
}

\solidline{1cm}    

\solidline{2em}

\solidline{1em}

\solidline{0.5em}

\bye
```

(requires `pdftex`; it could be made to work also with Knuth TeX, of course).

Comment: Wow this is like magic

Comment: If you think that's complicated, _don't click on any questions with glue, penalties, or `\catcode` in their name!_ :-)

Answer (score 45):

Just don't do this.

two `--` ligature to an n-dash and three `---` ligature to an em-dash so if you have a multiple of three `-` you have a row of em dashses which may or may not have white space between them depending on the font. use a `\rule` or `\hrulefill` to make a line.